# Song of multiple dances

Tags: dancing

**[Music Fans Topic Challenge #2 - Dancing](https://musicfans.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/403/music-fans-topic-challenge-2-dancing)**

---

Many songs have become hits on the back of an associated [dance craze](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5897/biggest-hit-dance-song), and of course, many dances can be done to more than one song.  But has any well-known song ever been strongly associated with two (or more) distinctly different dances?  Dance compilation songs like "Night of 1000 Dances" and "Watch Me!" do not count.

Comment: https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/5904/where-does-the-y-m-c-a-dance-comes-from, Y.M.C.A. has a initial dance in the chorus, then a more popular dance expanded and replaced it :-)

Comment: A lot of pop songs have many dances that can be done with them.  It's not uncommon on dance discussions to encounter dancers insisting one song is better for the cha-cha while the other is insisting on east-coast swing.